# KeyboardAvoidingView + React Navigation + Safe Area View = not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-safe-area-view

The problem I am having is while using a `react-navigation` stack navigator nested inside a tab navigator for a basic chat UI appearance, the keyboard was hiding the chat message input field at the bottom. So I tried `KeyboardAvoidingView` to bring the keyboard up to a visible position, but the keyboard wasn't showing. I have tried a solution that involves adding `headerHeight` to the `keyboardVerticalOffset` prop, but it seems to be about 50px off. For example, if I add `headerHeight + 50` to `keyboardVerticalOffset` everything looks great, but if I switched devices to an iPhone 5 or something, with a smaller screen, different SafeArea insets, etc, the keyboard would be in the wrong position again.

I am not sure what the culprit is exactly, but I am now thinking it's the SafeArea padding on top and/or bottom, which I have learned are the "insets". I am trying to use `useSafeAreaInsets`, but all the values return 0! I want to use those insets to add to the `keyboardVerticalOffset` prop so the avoiding view works properly.

I like the style of the tab bar right now, so I'd like to keep it with an increased height and padding and font size, but maybe I am doing it wrong with react native navigation? Maybe I cannot have this tab bar and stack navigator styling as I want with React Native? Regardless, I believe the insets should be returning a value, so I think that's where a problem lies.

Notice if I move the `<SafeAreaView>` block to surround the `<TouchableWithoutFeedback>`, instead of around the `<NavigationContainer>` block, and remove the 50 extra pixels added to the `keyboardVerticalOffset`, then the keyboard pushes the input field up properly, but the tab bar icons on iPhone 11 are squished. As I am writing this out, I am noticing that this change now has the bottom/topPadding variables returning values? If I then remove the `tabBarOptions`, I get a basic appearance of the tabs that work, but I like the design of my initial tabs much more.

**How do I maintain my current styling of the tab bar and have the keyboard avoid the chat input field on every device?**

(Note: The `useEffect` usage below is something I tried using the solution outlined in this issue: https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context/issues/54)

**App.js:**

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, KeyboardAvoidingView, TextInput, Text, Platform, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard, ActivityIndicator, SafeAreaView, ScrollView, Button, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator, useHeaderHeight } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import FontAwesome5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
import { useSafeAreaInsets, useSafeAreaFrame } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function TicketStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerStyle: { 
        backgroundColor: "dodgerblue",
        elevation: 0, // remove shadow on Android
        shadowOpacity: 0, // remove shadow on iOS
      },
      headerTintColor: "#fff",
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: "900",
        fontSize: 26,
      },

    }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Ticket">
        {(props) => <TicketScreen {...props} />}
      </Stack.Screen>
      <Stack.Screen name="Chat">
        {(props) => <ChatScreen {...props} />}
      </Stack.Screen>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text><FontAwesome5 name={"home"} size={20} color={"dodgerblue"} /> Home screen!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function TicketScreen(props){
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Ticket screen :)!</Text>
      <Button title="Go to Chat" onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Chat')} />
    </View>
  );
}

function CustomKeyboardAvoidingView({ children, style }) {
    const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight();
    console.log("headerHeight: " + headerHeight)
    console.log("StatusBar.currentHeight: " + StatusBar.currentHeight)

    const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
    console.log("insets.top: " + topPadding)
    console.log("insets.bottom: " + bottomPadding)

    const [bottomPadding, setBottomPadding] = useState(insets.bottom)
    const [topPadding, setTopPadding] = useState(insets.top)

    useEffect(() => {
      setBottomPadding(insets.bottom)
      setTopPadding(insets.top)

      console.log("topPadding: " + topPadding)
      console.log("bottomPadding: " + bottomPadding)
    }, [insets.bottom, insets.top])

    // const frame = useSafeAreaFrame();
    // const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height  
    // console.log("frame.height: " + frame.height)
    // console.log("windowHeight: " + windowHeight)
    // const safeAreaHeight = windowHeight - frame.height
    // console.log("safeAreaHeight: " + safeAreaHeight)
    // safeAreaHeight is too much, needs to just be bottom or top padding from safearea
    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
            style={style}
            behavior={Platform.OS == "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
            keyboardVerticalOffset={headerHeight + 50}
        >
            {children}
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
}

function ChatScreen(){
  return(
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
        <CustomKeyboardAvoidingView style={{backgroundColor: "#fff", flex: 1, flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
          <View style={{backgroundColor: "dodgerblue", paddingVertical: 15}}>
              <View style={{ margin: 10, marginBottom: 15}}>
                  <ActivityIndicator size="large" style={{marginBottom: 10}}/>
                  <Text>Waiting for more info here....</Text>
              </View>
          </View>

          <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor: "tomato", paddingVertical: 15}}>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
          </ScrollView>
          
          <View style={{backgroundColor: "yellow", paddingVertical: 15}}>
              <TextInput placeholder="Type your message here..." />
          </View>
        </CustomKeyboardAvoidingView>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  )
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

// TODO:
// - removing safeareaview makes tabs squished and icon nearly invisible, but chat message input fields avoids keyboard properly (squished can be fixed by removing tabBarOptions)
// - having safeareaview makes tabs look good, but chat message input field is hidden by keyboard
// - safeareainsets? why are they 0? i would be adding the bottom or top padding of insets to the vertical offset of the keyboard avoiding view.
export default class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: "dodgerblue"}}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Tab.Navigator
            screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
              tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => {
                let iconName;

                if (route.name === 'Home') {
                  iconName = 'home';
                } else if (route.name === 'Ticket') {
                  iconName = 'question';
                }
                return <FontAwesome5 name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
              },
            })}
            tabBarOptions={{
              style: {
                height: 70
              }, 
              activeTintColor: "#fff",
              inactiveTintColor: "dodgerblue",
              inactiveBackgroundColor: "#fff",
              activeBackgroundColor: "dodgerblue",                               
              tabStyle: {
                paddingTop: 10,
                paddingBottom: 10
              },
              labelStyle: {
                fontSize: 14
              },
            }}>
            <Tab.Screen name="Home">
              {(props) => <HomeScreen {...props} />}
            </Tab.Screen>
            <Tab.Screen name="Ticket">
              {(props) => <TicketStack {...props} />}
            </Tab.Screen>
          </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "ReactNativeTest",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.9.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.8",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.11.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.11.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "25.5.1",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "jest": "25.5.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So as Alex over at this [Github issue](https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context/issues/153#issuecomment-716425537) pointed out, wrapping the app in `SafeAreaProvider` fixes the insets not returning values properly.

The Tab bar was still squished with `SafeAreaView` wrapping the `NavigationContainer` and I fixed that by adding a height of 70 to `tabStyle` prop of `Tab.Navigator`. Then another issue arose, where the Stack Header of the TicketScreen was way too large and was fixed from this [Github issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5936) by adding `headerStatusBarHeight: 0` to `Stack.Navigator` `screenOptions` prop. The insets were only returning properly inside `useEffect` with a `setState` usage, which I then used the `topPadding` value to add to the `keyboardVerticalOffset` prop and the keyboard was popping up without hiding the input field on an iPhone 11 and iPhone 6s!

Update note: Make sure to also set `keyboardHidesTabBar: (Platform.OS == "ios" ? false : true)` as a prop on `Tab.Navigator`.

Here's the full working code:

```js
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, KeyboardAvoidingView, TextInput, Text, Platform, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard, ActivityIndicator, SafeAreaView, ScrollView, Button, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator, useHeaderHeight } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import FontAwesome5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
import { useSafeAreaInsets, SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function TicketStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerStatusBarHeight: 0, // Header had increased size with SafeArea for some reason (https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5936)
        headerStyle: { 
          backgroundColor: "dodgerblue",
          elevation: 0, // remove shadow on Android
          shadowOpacity: 0, // remove shadow on iOS
        },
        headerTintColor: "#fff",
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: "900",
          fontSize: 26,
        },
      }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Ticket">
        {(props) => <TicketScreen {...props} />}
      </Stack.Screen>
      <Stack.Screen name="Chat">
        {(props) => <ChatScreen {...props} />}
      </Stack.Screen>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text><FontAwesome5 name={"home"} size={20} color={"dodgerblue"} />Home screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function TicketScreen(props){
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Ticket screen</Text>
      <Button title="Go to Chat" onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Chat')} />
    </View>
  );
}

function CustomKeyboardAvoidingView({ children, style }) {
    const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight();
    console.log("headerHeight: " + headerHeight)
    console.log("StatusBar.currentHeight: " + StatusBar.currentHeight)

    const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
    const [bottomPadding, setBottomPadding] = useState(insets.bottom)
    const [topPadding, setTopPadding] = useState(insets.top)

    useEffect(() => {
      // This useEffect is needed because insets are undefined at first for some reason
      // https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context/issues/54
      setBottomPadding(insets.bottom)
      setTopPadding(insets.top)

      console.log("topPadding: " + topPadding)
      console.log("bottomPadding: " + bottomPadding)
    }, [insets.bottom, insets.top])

    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
            style={style}
            behavior={Platform.OS == "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
            keyboardVerticalOffset={headerHeight + topPadding + StatusBar.currentHeight}
        >
            {children}
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
}

function ChatScreen(){
  return(
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
        <CustomKeyboardAvoidingView style={{backgroundColor: "#fff", flex: 1, flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
          <View style={{backgroundColor: "dodgerblue", paddingVertical: 15}}>
              <View style={{ margin: 10, marginBottom: 15}}>
                  <ActivityIndicator size="large" style={{marginBottom: 10}}/>
                  <Text>Waiting for more info here....</Text>
              </View>
          </View>

          <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor: "tomato", paddingVertical: 15}}>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
              <Text>Chat messages</Text>
          </ScrollView>
          
          <View style={{backgroundColor: "yellow", paddingVertical: 15}}>
              <TextInput placeholder="Type your message here..." />
          </View>
        </CustomKeyboardAvoidingView>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  )
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: "dodgerblue"}}>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Tab.Navigator
              screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
                tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => {
                  let iconName;

                  if (route.name === 'Home') {
                    iconName = 'home';
                  } else if (route.name === 'Ticket') {
                    iconName = 'question';
                  }
                  return <FontAwesome5 name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
                },
              })}
              tabBarOptions={{
                style: {
                  height: 70
                }, 
                activeTintColor: "#fff",
                inactiveTintColor: "dodgerblue",
                inactiveBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                activeBackgroundColor: "dodgerblue",                               
                tabStyle: {
                  paddingTop: 10,
                  paddingBottom: 10,
                  height: 70
                },
                labelStyle: {
                  fontSize: 14
                },
                keyboardHidesTabBar: (Platform.OS == "ios" ? false : true)
              }}>
              <Tab.Screen name="Home">
                {(props) => <HomeScreen {...props} />}
              </Tab.Screen>
              <Tab.Screen name="Ticket">
                {(props) => <TicketStack {...props} />}
              </Tab.Screen>
            </Tab.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like I posted in the corresponding [GitHub issue](https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context/issues/153#issuecomment-716425537), wrapping the App in `<SafeAreaProvider>` fixes the issue:

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        ...
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out mate! There were still some other issues, as I outlined in the answer above

Comment: @douglasrcjames Oh, my bad for not reading the full question! Glad you fixed all your issues. :)

Comment: doesnt work for me